# Representing polymorphism with unification-fd

Tags: haskell, polymorphism, representation, hindley-milner

I'd like to use the [`unification-fd`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/unification-fd) package to implement a  simple typechecker for a Hindley-Milner type system. This requires the representation of polymorphic ("forall") types.

What's the best way of representing these types? The variables provided by `unification-fd`, i.e. the `UVar` stuff, is for unification (meta)variables, not for variables in the object language. Some possibilities I've pondered:

1. Add a constructor for type variables to my base functor representing types:

   ```
   data TyF tcon tv a
       = TCon tcon [a]
       | TVar tv
   ```

   with `zipMatch`  only unifying equal `TVar`s. Type instantiation consistently replaces every `UTerm (TVar a)` with a `freeVar`.
2. (Ab)use `UVar`s for type variables, and replace them with `freeVar`s when instantiating. Requires tracking of universial vs. existential `UVar`s to know which ones to replace.
3. Leave `TVar` out of `TyF`, use separate `UTerm (TyF tcon) IntVar` for monomorpic types during typechecking, `UTerm (TyF tcon) tv` for polymorphic types visible from the outside, and `UTerm (TyF tcon) (Either tv IntVar)` during typechecking for intermediate, `let`-bound variables.

Which would be best? Is there some other way I haven't thought of?